# Is Web API:S Fetch() parallell or async?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, async-await, fetch, fetch-api

I'm having trouble finding the answer to this.
When we call fetch(), is the browser opening a new thread or is the call just put in the microqueue?

Comment: Parallel *is* async. Not all async is parallel, however.

Comment: The operation itself is async. Don’t confuse concurrency with parallelism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is sort of "both":

- The network request itself is processed in parallel with anything else happening on your JavaScript thread, not on the JavaScript thread. (In all major browsers.)
- When the network request is complete, a promise reaction (fulfillment or rejection) is queued to be picked up by the JavaScript thread when it's next checking the relevant queue. (I *think* what happens is that the browser queues a task that settles the promise, which in turn queues any relevant promise reactions in the microtask queue. The details don't really matter, though; fundamentally, once the network request is complete, a task/microtask is queued somewhere for any promise reactions that need to happen, and picked up by the JavaScript thread like other tasks/microtasks.)

Comment: I feel it's really only one kind of answer. The second part happens with all promise-based async tasks. It's not something special for `fetch`. OP seems to be confusing things because the question reads like "Is Lassie a dog or an animal?"

Comment: @VLAZ - Maybe. I thought the second part was relevant because of the first part. Not everyone is aware of JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics, so one *could* imagine a situation where once the parallel work is complete, whatever the JavaScript code is doing could be suspended in the middle and the promise reaction processed. As you and I know, that isn't what happens though. :-)

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah so I was just wondering if the network call itself was put in the microqueue to start with, or if it starts off running parallel in a different thread, and then put in the microqueue. :)

Comment: @AlfredOdling - The network task will probably be put in *some* queue (for the networking part of the browser to handle, since they only allow X number of concurrent network operations), but not a JavaScript-related one. :-)